# Terminal/sink state in pytransitions

Tags: python, transition, state-machine, pytransitions

I am using [pytransitions](https://pypi.org/project/transitions/) with a state machine for example

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData


class Matter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        transitions = [
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'}
        ]
        self.machine = Machine(
                model=self,
                states=['solid', 'liquid', 'gas'],
                transitions=transitions,
                initial='solid',
                send_event=True
        )

    def on_enter_gas(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering gas from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_liquid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering liquid from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_solid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering solid from {event.transition.source}")
```

I would like to add a state, for which any trigger remains in the same state, without invoking a transition, and without explicitly specifying every possible trigger, and also without ignoring all invalid triggers (as this is very good for debugging).

I would like for example a state `crystal` which can be reached by triggering `crystalize` from `liquid`, for which any event will do nothing.

Can this be achieved with the library?

Another way to phrase this question would be some way to `ignore_invalid_triggers=True` only for a specific state, not all states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to transitions, states can also be defined with dictionaries:

```py
from transitions import Machine, MachineError


class Matter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        transitions = [
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'},
            # add a transition to 'crystal' which is valid from anywhere
            {'trigger': 'crystallize', 'source': '*', 'dest': 'crystal'},
        ]
        self.machine = Machine(
                model=self,
                states=['solid', 'liquid', 'gas',
                        # initialized 'crystal' with dictionary
                        {'name': 'crystal', 'ignore_invalid_triggers': True}],
                transitions=transitions,
                initial='solid',
                send_event=True
        )


m = Matter()
assert m.is_solid()
try:
    m.cool()  # raises a machine error since cool cannot be called from 'solid'
    assert False
except MachineError:
    pass
assert m.crystallize()  # transitions to 'crystal'
assert m.is_crystal()
assert not m.heat()  # note that the transition will return 'False' since it did not happen but no exception was thrown
assert m.is_crystal()  # state machine is still in state 'crystal'
```

Instead of `{'name': 'crystal', 'ignore_invalid_triggers': True}` you could also pass `State(name='crystal', ignore_invalid_triggers=True)` instead.
This form is mentioned in the [documentation's state section](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#states):

> But in some cases, you might want to silently ignore invalid triggers. You can do this by setting ignore_invalid_triggers=True (either on a state-by-state basis, or globally for all states):

Comment: Thanks! How can I use either method when the states are defined as an enum?

Comment: For Enums, you need to pass the values separately and replace `States.CRYSTAL` with the approriate `dict`: `states=[s if s != States.CRYSTAL else dict(name=States.CRYSTAL, ignore_invalid_triggers=True) for s in States]`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was after the machine was already instantiated with its transitions:

```
self.machine.get_state(states.crystal.name).ignore_invalid_triggers = True
```

I really don't like that solution, as it defeats the very clean design of transitions initialization as a list, but it is all I could find and it does work.

Comment: You can omit `.name` when you are using `Enums`: `self.machine.get_state(states.crystal).ignore_invalid_triggers = True`